# Where request comes from (php)

Tags: php, mysql, redirect, sql-delete

I have 3 php pages. These are related to my message system.

- 1st file is `inbox.php`
- 2nd file is `sent.php`
- 3rd file is `delete_message.php`

My questions is about redirecting with `header('Location:xxx');` I want to redirect user to where from he/she request delete query.

For example if he/she delete a message from inbox I want to redirect him to `inbox.php`, else he/she must redirected to `sent.php`

What I should add to my delete script?

```
<?php

include '../config/db.connect.php';

$m_id = $_GET['message_id'];
$delete = $db->exec("DELETE FROM message WHERE message_id ='$m_id'");

if ( $delete ) {

header("Location:../message_sent.php");
} 

else {

echo "delete error..";
echo "An error message...");
}
?>
```

Comment: Add a session with your url in it. after delete call that session and redirect using that url.

Comment: use back_url and on the delete page, extract the back_url from main url and user it in header("...")

Comment: @KAsh - what you wrote is a complete nonsense. Please don't advise people if you yourself have no clue what you're talking about.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']` to get the previous page url.